# Pandas set cell issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am running below code and getting an error. 
I can run:

```
r.at[0,'_foreign_notional_sum'] = s
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Error producing code:

```
s=0
r['_foreign_notional_sum'] = 0.0
for index,row in r.iterrows():
  s=s+r._foreign_notional
  index
  r.at[index,'_foreign_notional_sum'] = s
```

## -- error:

File "pandas/_libs/src\util.pxd", line 150, in util.set_value_at
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 142, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means `s` is a sequence. I suppose your `r._foreign_notional` is a Series, and your `s + r._foreign_notional` is a giving you a Series (hence `s = s + r._foreign_notional` is a Series).

You are probably looking for `s += row['_foreign_notional']`.

Please update your code though, as the current syntax is not valid.

If you are looking to update an entire column, you can simply use `r['_foreign_notional_sum'] += s`.